# Найти и выделить текст в Richtextbox. Не выделяется первое слово

Tags: c#, winforms, строки, поиск, textbox

Вот метод поиска строки в двух формах:

```
        private void findWordInVoc_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = 0;
        string text = "";
        string temp = "";
        string foundWord = Properties.Settings.Default.foundWord;
        RichTextBox rtx = new RichTextBox();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {

            if (i == 0) //форма вывода сгенерированных слов
            {
                rtx = rtxtbox_output;
                text = rtxtbox_output.Text;
                temp = text;
                text = "";
                text = temp;
            }
            else if (i == 1)//форма загрузки с файла словаря
            {
                rtx = rtxtbox_loadFromVocFile;
                text = rtxtbox_loadFromVocFile.Text;
                temp = text;
                text = "";
                text = temp;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(foundWord))
            {
                while (index < text.LastIndexOf(foundWord))
                {
                    rtx.Find(foundWord,index,
                        rtx.TextLength,RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                    rtx.SelectionBackColor = SystemColors.Control;
                    index = text.IndexOf(foundWord,index) + 1;
                }
            }
            index = 0;
            while (index < text.LastIndexOf(txtbox_input.Text))
            {
                rtx.Find(txtbox_input.Text,index,
                    rtx.TextLength,RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                rtx.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
                index = text.IndexOf(txtbox_input.Text,index) + 1;
            }
        }
        rtx.ScrollToCaret();
        Properties.Settings.Default.foundWord = txtbox_input.Text;
    }
```

Проблема в том, что не выделяется первое слово стоящее в richtextbox - ни в первом ни во втором. Начиная со второго все идет нормально. Что я пропустил.
Может быть проблема в коде, который записывает строку в форму?
Вот метод, что генерирует строку:

```
 public string Main(
        string txtbox_input_text,
        string txtbox_comment_text,
        int cbb_grammarType_index)
    {
        string sylStructure = "";
        string wordStr = null;
        string wordType = null;

        if (cbb_grammarType_index == 3)
        {
            sylStructure = SylStructRandom(true);
        }
        else if (cbb_grammarType_index == 0 ||
            cbb_grammarType_index == 1 ||
            cbb_grammarType_index == 2)
        {
            sylStructure = SylStructRandom(false);
            if (sylStructure == "cv")
            {
                int p = rGen.Next(1,4);//шанс 1 из 3, что согласная будет j
                if (p == 1) sylStructure += "jv";
            }
            else
            {
                if (DefineFullMeaningWordsSylAmount() != 1)
                    sylStructure = SylStructRandom(false);
            }
        }
        sylStructure = DeleteThirdCons(sylStructure);
        wordStr = ConvertSylStructToWordStr(sylStructure);
        switch (cbb_grammarType_index)
        {
            case 0:
                wordType = "n";
                break;
            case 1:
                wordType = "v";
                break;
            case 2:
                wordType = "a";
                break;
            case 3:
                wordType = "p";
                break;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox_comment_text))
            txtbox_comment_text = " (" + txtbox_comment_text + ")";
        return txtbox_input_text + " " + wordStr + " " + wordType
            + txtbox_comment_text + "\r\n";
    }
```

А вот, что вызывает предыдущий и записывает результат в форму:

```
void GenerateAndOutput()
    {
        WGen wg = new WGen();
        rtxtbox_output.Text+= wg.Main(
            txtbox_input.Text,
            txtbox_comment.Text,
            cbb_grammarType.SelectedIndex);
        txtbox_input.Clear();
        txtbox_comment.Clear();
        txtbox_input.Focus();
    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я пропустил. Вроде бы мелочь, но очень бросается в глаза

Примеры:
[image: Первое слово в richtextbox не выделяется]

[image: второе выделяется]

[image: третье тоже]

Comment: вообще то это не вопрос, а завуалированная просьба за вас отладить код. Сделайте это сами, поставьте точку останова в нужном месте и пройдите по шагам исполнение кода, смотрите значения нужных переменных и найдете где криво написано.

Comment: И на том спасибо